# Detecting and getting dirty regions in WPF?

Tags: wpf, direct3d, redraw, directdraw

Any way of getting the redraw/dirty regions in a WPF application?

I would like to have them programmatically and not only visualized.

My goal is to know when and what has redrawn in a WPF app for a kind of remoting application.

Comment: Take a look at the WPF Performance Suite (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx), at least it should help you getting started.

Comment: WPF PS can visualize dirty regions (good) but I still also need the regions programatically.

Comment: I don't think this is available. If you look at WPF PS with a tool such as reflector, you'll see the dirty region visualization is implemented in a native dll (milctrl_v0300_x86.dll or milctrl_v0300_x64.dll). Even with this dll, only the switch show/hide dirty regions is available, not the region coordinates.